# Chat flag notification

Tags: discussion, notifications, chat, flags

10k users can see flags in chat. What are we suppose to do with it, and why these notifications don't go away after "reading" them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same as the flags list on the main site. You can see what posts have spam/offensive flags and add your own if you like; posts are killed when they get to six flags. The only reason it seems different is on the main site you need to go to a special page to see the list, but on chat there's the special page *and* the indicator on your gravatar, so you notice it more

Comment: *so you notice it more*: so it annoys you more :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: +1 If I could do anything about these flagged messages then I'd be happy to see them. But right now all I can do is look at a list of flags, which is a little pointless without the ability to do anything with them.

Comment: Well, the thing is, you *can* do something about them, just not that much. All you can do is go to the chat-room in question and add your own. In other words, if you think the flag is well-deserved, you can help push it towards that limit of 6 flags, in order to get rid of it. That's it. I agree, it annoys me too, but once I got over the initial annoyance hurdle, they don't bother me much. Now, the main problem as I see it is that I never know if that (2) there now, are the same 2 flags I looked at yesterday. I wish they would add some way for me to say "OK, I've looked at them, now go away".

Answer (score 5):

Not allowing to clear these flags seems a recipe for removing any once-flagged message — just to get rid of that damn blue circle.

At least spam/offensive flags on the main site aren't thrust at you, so you effectively have to watch them only if you're interested; and this seems to work fine.  Chat flags need a similar "I don't care" feature.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an option to "ignore this flag" should be added, to remove the notification?  Otherwise, it seems like many, many notifications will be piling up (or else everything that gets one flag will get flagged to oblivion).